# GLEW and GLFW on Mac OS X (standalone)

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl, glfw, glew

I built a project on XCode using glew and glfw. The CMake file was given to me by a tutorial, so I don't actually know how to make one of the cpp files build by itself. When I pasted the code into a new standalone file, I got the errors:

```
error: GL/glew.h: No such file or directory
error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory
```

I googled these errors, but most of the solutions were for Linux and did not work for my Mac. GLEW and GLFW are indeed installed on my system, since I was using them successfully in my XCode project. I just don't know how to set the correct paths when I am compiling a standalone cpp file at the command line using g++.

Answer (score 0):

use -I at the command line to indicate which include paths the compiler should search

Comment: Yes, but how exactly?

Comment: so the compiler you are using is gcc (i think)... just search on "gcc include path": http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html